# Split string using split() method

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to split a string into array but the regex I am using doesn't seem to work

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetURLParameter(sParam) 
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var product= GetURLParameter("name");
        var producttype=GetURLParameter("type");
        var prod = product.replace(/%20/g," ");
        var productname = prod.split('\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])');
        alert(productname[0]);
        });
    </script>
```

My Input String is "`Calpol Plus 200MG`"

Expected output is `array[0] = "Calpol Plus"` and `array[1] = "200MG"`

The regex I am using is `\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
"Calpol Plus 200MG".split('\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])')
```

You must use one of these:

- `RegExp` constructor to convert your string to a regular expression:

  ```
  "Calpol Plus 200MG".split(RegExp('\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])'))
  ```
- Directly use a regular expression literal:

  ```
  "Calpol Plus 200MG".split(/\s+(?=\d+M[LG])/)
  ```

  Note in this case you don't need to scape the `\` characters with another `\`.

Answer (score 3):

You passed your regex as a string, see?

```
var productname = prod.split('\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])');
```

You need to pass it as a regex literal:

```
var productname = prod.split(/\\s+(?=\\d+M[LG])/);
```

`split()` will split either by a regex, or by a substring, depending on what is passed.

Comment: But now you should remove the escaping `\\`, shouldn't you?

Comment: No, because it still needs to be escaped for a regex.

Comment: I disagree, so I posted [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27770346/1529630) :)